# React conditional formatting ternary

Tags: reactjs

Dumb question. I am trying to conditionally render elements based on the length of an array which is a prop.

```
return (
<div>
     {this.props.events.length > 0 ? <div>True</div> : <div>False</div>}
</div>
);
```

The true renders fine, but false does not. Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: False only gets executed if the length is less than 0.

Comment: Check the `this.props.events.length`

Comment: False only gets executed if the length is less OR equal to 0

Comment: Try removing greater than 0

Comment: Nothing wrong with the condition, most probably the value is always greate than 0, this is why it is values true, Check this.props.events.length  value

Answer (score 1):

js

```
export default ({ events }) => {
  return <div>{events.length > 0 ? <div>True</div> : <div>False</div>}</div>;
};
```

App.js

```
<Hello events={[]} />
<Hello events={[1]} />
```

that outputs: `False` and `True`

[a working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-36egep?file=index.js)

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely bemused. the check for greater than 0 did not work, however, greater than or equal to 1 did. Not sure if it is of my own doing. Anyway, thank you for all your help.